# Javascripts not working after Django update

Tags: javascript, django

I updated my Django 1.9 application to Django 3.1 following the changes mentioned in the releases.
The application is running, but the javascripts are not showing the same bevhavior.

```
<a href="{% url field.label_tag|cut:field.label|striptags prj_pk=ProjectId %}" class="add-another" id="add_{{field.auto_id}}" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"></a>
```

This line previously showed + button to open a new form but now the + button is not seen on the webpage.
What has changed with respect to Javascripts in Django 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't render javascript in HTML tags properly. The reason is that the Javascript is static and when it's placed directly inside an HTML template, Django will treat it as HTML and may render it incorrectly. So, use a separate static js file to create a function to call on click using jquery.

```
$("#some-id").click(function() {
     //do something here
})
```